# Angular Provider for Logged In User

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular application, I store the logged-in user as a `BehaviorSubject` in my AuthenticationService:

```js
export class AuthenticationService {

  private user$$ : BehaviorSubject<AppUser>;

  // ...

  // simplified version of actual method
  authenticateUser(username : string) : AppUser {

     return this.http.get(AUTH_URL)
       pipe(
         tap(user => this.user.next(user$$)
         ...
       );
  }

  getCurrentUser() : Observable<AppUser> {
    // only provide to end as read-only observable
    return this.user$$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

However, since many of my components need the user, I tend to autowire the AuthenticationService in those components:

```
  private user : AppUser;

  constructor(authService : AuthenticationService) {}

  ngOnInit() : void {

    this.authService.user$
      pipe(
        tap((user) => this.user = user),
        // etc
      )
      .subscribe();

  }
```

What I want to do is create a custom provider (leaving out the code for the CURRENT_USER injection token):

```js
@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [
    { provide : CURRENT_USER, useFactory: (authenticationService : AuthenticationService) => authenticationService.getCurrentUser()), deps: [AuthenticationService] }
  ]
})
```

The advantage to doing this would be to decouple the AuthenticationService from the various components. But what I need to know is if this is considered poor practice and will lead to undesired effects (memory leaks, etc).

Comment: It seems confusing to receive an observable or a promise as a dependency. Otherwise it makes sense

Comment: @AluanHaddad possibly, but by making the user an observable, the components aren't using an old version of user if it changes, or is invalidated at logout.

Comment: right I just mean it might be surprising to inject an observable. I assume you'd use a `ReplaySubject<User>` or something similar underneath so that creating something which injects the user after it's been retrieved can still access the user. But now we're talking about not just injecting an observable but a specific kind of multicasting observable that the user has to be aware of.